# I want to update my stock quantity after making a sale but I'm not able to insert a new sale after creating the trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi I'm building a vinyl record store database and I want to update the stock quantity after making a sale.
These are the codes for my order table:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_INFO (
ORDER_ID INT NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL,
RECORD_ID1 VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
RECORD1_QUANT INT NOT NULL,
RECORD_ID2 VARCHAR (50) NULL,
RECORD2_QUANT INT NULL,
RECORD_ID3 VARCHAR (50) NULL,
RECORD3_QUANT INT NULL,
RECORD_ID4 VARCHAR (50) NULL,
RECORD4_QUANT INT NULL,
RECORD_ID5 VARCHAR (50) NULL,
RECORD5_QUANT INT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER_INFO PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID));
```

These are the codes for my stock table:

```
CREATE TABLE STOCK_INFO (
RECORD_ID VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
RECORD_TITLE VARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
RECORD_ARTIST VARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
RECORD_LABEL VARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
RELEASE_YEAR YEAR NULL,
GENRE1 VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
GENRE2 VARCHAR (50) NULL,
MINTORNOT VARCHAR (3) NOT NULL,
PRICE DECIMAL (10,2) NOT NULL,
STOCK_QUANTITY INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_STOCK_INFO PRIMARY KEY (RECORD_ID));
```

And this is the trigger I created:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Stockquantity
AFTER INSERT ON ORDER_INFO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE STOCK_INFO
SET STOCK_QUANTITY = STOCK_QUANTITY - RECORD1_QUANT WHERE RECORD_ID = RECORD_ID1;
UPDATE STOCK_INFO
SET STOCK_QUANTITY = STOCK_QUANTITY - RECORD2_QUANT WHERE RECORD_ID = RECORD_ID2;
UPDATE STOCK_INFO
SET STOCK_QUANTITY = STOCK_QUANTITY - RECORD3_QUANT WHERE RECORD_ID = RECORD_ID3;
UPDATE STOCK_INFO
SET STOCK_QUANTITY = STOCK_QUANTITY - RECORD4_QUANT WHERE RECORD_ID = RECORD_ID4;
UPDATE STOCK_INFO
SET STOCK_QUANTITY = STOCK_QUANTITY - RECORD5_QUANT WHERE RECORD_ID = RECORD_ID5;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger has been created, but when I'm trying to insert a new sale into the ORDER_INFO table, MySQL gives me the "Unkown Column 'RECORD_ID1' in 'Where' clause". I am really confused, can anyone see where the problem is and how to correct it? Thank you!

I didn't really "try" anything--I mean I tried to think of it as a procedure or a function but after reading a bunch of material I think it makes sense to make it as a trigger instead of a procedure? But all the examples I read are usually simple

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Update
AFTER INSERT ON ORDER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE STOCK
SET STOCK_QUANTITY = STOCK_QUANTITY - ORDER_QUANTITY WHERE STOCK_ID = GOODS_ID;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Does it have anything to do with the way I design my order table? Should I change it and how can I change it?

Comment: Do you have a limit of 5 items per order ?
Create a table order and a table order_items with a 1-n relation instead

Comment: In an after insert trigger I would expect to see reference to NEW.  values please review manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html ,

Comment: @Sylwit Yep that sounds much better, I have created a table called ORDERS_RECORDS of all the order_id and record_id and quantity combination, and created a trigger as following `CREATE TRIGGER Update_Stockquantity
AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS_RECORDS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE STOCK_INFO
SET STOCK_QUANTITY = STOCK_QUANTITY - QUANTITY WHERE RECORD_ID = RID;
END //
DELIMITER ; ` But when I insert into the ORDERS_RECORDS table, similar thing happened to me as before--it says there's an unknown column 'RID' in 'where clause'

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon I tried adding 'NEW' but it would still tell me "unkown column 'QUANTITY' in 'NEW')